# Restrict Wordpress Page by IP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress website and I want to restrict one of the pages to be accessible only by specific IPs. The page is a template for my WordPress theme. The php file of the template is called alley.php

Here is what I tried in the .htaccess file, placed in the template directory

```
<FilesMatch alley.php>
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

but it's not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, you had the allow and deny the wrong way around

```
<Files alley.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>
```

Comment: Hi Howlin, thanks for the reply, but I still can access the page from all IPs.

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh on the page to double check? Also the htaccess needs to be in the same directory as the alley.php file.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/apache(2?) restart

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin will be helpful for you,

http://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/