# Wordpress and AngularJS setup

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angularjs

Since I am completely fed up with Wordpress' theming system, I have been looking at alternatives for building Wordpress themes. One possibility is to use AngularJS with Wordpress as the backend. The JSON response would be provided by the WP-API plugin. This is coming together rather nicely, but I just had one question about how to structure my files.

One way is to let wordpress live on its own inside the angular app folder, like this:
project

`app
│   README.md
│   index.html
│
└───js
    │   app.js
    │   controllers.js
    │
    styles
    │   style.css
    │   style.min.css
    │
    Wordpress
        index.php
        wp-config.php
        etc...`

The API can be reached through: http://example.com/json-api/

And the backend can be reached through: http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin

But, this does mean that the users can simply see the normal Wordpress theme by going to http://example.com/wordpress which is of course something that I don't want.

The second possibility is to let the angular app live inside the dedicated Wordpress theme folder, like we're used to. The reason why I don't prefer this is because then the user still has to go through all of Wordpress' processes and loops, which I think are very inefficient.

Basically, the only thing that I need is the wp-admin folder and the WP-API plugin to be working. Is this possible? If not: how can I block the user from accessing the Wordpress folder, while still being able to access the wp-content/upload & wp-admin & json-api folder?

Hope the question is clear enough, after two full days of trying to figure this out it all becomes kind of hazy.

Comment: This works by configuring your webserver the way you need it. However this is not straight forward because wordpress lacks of structure for your needs in it's URL layout. One use-case that comes to mind is: [How to Protect Uploads, if User is not Logged In?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/37144/178) - That Wordpress Development Q&A site perhaps is even a better venue for your question, and some folks over there might be interested in what you do, too. Don't forget to specify which webserver you're using.

Comment: i actually dont see the point of this, either use WP or dont. I think you might be experiencing a learning curve that all WP developers experience. You need to know when theme/plugins are loaded into the filesystem, hence the use of add_action/add_filter to allow you to "plugin" code later in the sequence. If you are building a php rendered website with some ajax functionality, WP can handle this no problem. If you want something with a lot of ajax, it gets a bit slow and the adv of using Wp as a backend to using other methods for managing your backend diminishes.

Comment: Hakre: Thanks for the referral, I'll certainly look into it. David: This has nothing to do with a learning curve. I have been coding for WP for over 6 years now, so I know it quite well. The reason I'm thinking of making this switch is because I'm very dissatisfied with the way WP is progressing. Especially considering the likes of other large PHP projects like Laravel. I am afraid that WP will eventually fall behind. Therefore I am trying to introduce more modern techniques in my project, like AngularJS. The only reason why I still want to use WP is because many clients just love the backend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict Wordpress Page by IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477956/restrict-wordpress-page-by-ip)